# Pytorch cuda version can not install

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu

In the beginning, I checked my cuda version using `nvcc --version` command and it shows version as **10.2**
So i started to install pytorch with cuda based on instruction in [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) so I tried with bellow command in anaconda prompt with python 3.8.3 virtual environment

`conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

in terminal it shows

```
    added / updated specs:
        - cudatoolkit=10.2
        - pytorch
        - torchaudio
        - torchvision

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cudatoolkit: 10.2.89-h74a9793_1
    pytorch:     1.7.0-py3.8_cpu_0  pytorch [cpuonly]
    torchaudio:  0.7.0-py38         pytorch
    torchvision: 0.8.1-py38_cpu     pytorch [cpuonly]
```

there are no any errors in installing process and then I try with below codes in notebook by activating this installed environment

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__, torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0) if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'CPU')
```

output was `1.7.0 CPU`

so I run `conda list PyTorch` command in anaconda prompt

it also shows below output

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytorch                   1.7.0               py3.8_cpu_0  [cpuonly]  pytorch
```

why it didn't install the GPU version and how can I fix this

Thank you

Comment: What type of GPU do you have? What is the version of your GPU drivers?

Comment: @jodag GPU = nvidia 940MX and  driver version = 456.38

Comment: Oops deleted previous comment as it was incorrect. The problem is that while your card supports cuda 10.2, pytorch binaries are not provided with support for compute capability 5.0. So that means you'll need to rebuild pytorch from source.

Comment: @jodag can you please provide me any documented resource link or guidance  for to that

Comment: found it  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source i'll try thank you @jodag

Comment: Also [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1596116/1011961) is applicable if you're on Windows 10

Answer (score -1):

I am using Python version `3.6.13` and all the same you used here.
You can try changing the Python version in another virtual environment and it should work.

**PS**: A thing to keep in mind is my OS is windows 10

Picture of `PyTorch` GPU working:

[image]